# Resolving Netbeans Library conflict, when using Subversion

Tags: java, svn, version-control, netbeans, project-management

I have a Netbeans Java Project under Subversion (svn). This is shared with another guy working on the project.

The project requires an external library that we have as a jar file. Now, when either of us makes a change and commits it, the project's library dependencies fail as we have different paths for the library ( as we are working on different machines the location of the `jar` file is different ).

This means that every time I update my repository, I have to resolve library dependencies.

Is there a way I can prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1st way: You can use NetBeans Library support.

Go to Tools->Libraries, and new Library with your jar. Name it the same way on both machines and include to your NB project as Library rather then direct path to jar.

### 2nd way: use relative path.

Agree on having jar located at `../lib/foo.jar` and use this path in NB project

### 3rd way: use property file.

Add file named, for example, `build.properties` but don't commit it to svn. So both of you will have different local version of that file.

Content should be something like next:

```
myproject.library.foojar=C:/foopath/foo.jar
```

In your `build.xml` include this file:

```
   <property file="../build.properties"/>
```

In your `nbproject/project.properties` find a reference to the jar -- it will look like:

```
file.reference.foo.jar=C:/foopath/foo.jar
```

change it to

```
file.reference.foo.jar=${myproject.library.foojar}
```

Also you may want to add `build.properties` into ignore list for svn to avoid commiting it.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use Maven to control library dependencies(jars). It is easy to use and  NetBeans has a module to use it easily.

Maven download all the dependencies you declared into a local repertory so you don't need to worried about managing libraries, Maven do it for you.
Also with this module you can search libraries in the Maven repertory(Has a lot of java librarys) only you need to type the name and maven download it for you.

Here there are some links for how to use Maven With NetBeans:
http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-maven-quickstart.html

http://today.java.net/article/2009/10/14/working-maven-netbeans-671